# How to unlock the mouse in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, scripting, mouse, roblox

I want to make a game using the weapons ROBLOX weapons, [here](https://www.roblox.com/library/4842197274/Pistol) is a link to one of them. They were in the ROBLOX Fortnite set. I want to make a weapon selection screen but I don't know how to unlock the mouse so that you can select the weapon in a GUI. What I have right now is a GUI where you can click what weapon you want. Once you choose that weapon it copies it from replicated storage and puts the copy into the players backpack. It disables the GUI when you select and re-enables it when you respawn. As soon as you join in it allows you to select, but when you select the weapon the first time the weapon locks your mouse and I can't figure out how unlock it. Does anyone know how to help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UserInputService` to do so.

```lua
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

--Use this to access stuff
UserInputService.MouseBehavior = Enum.MouseBehavior.Default
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for replying, however when I put that in (I made it to where when the weapon select GUI is enabled it unlocks the mouse using that script by firing an event that unlocks it) and it did not work. I used print Debugging and I am firing the script off it just isn't unlocking. The issue could possibly be like the weapons make your mouse invisible.